# Issues installing AWS Linux terminal on a MacBook Air: “replace aws/THIRD_PARTY_LICENSES?”

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I am using the terminal on my MacBook Air to install AWS Linux. I am completely new to this. I keep getting this error and cannot figure out how to trouble shoot it.

```
Archive:  awscliv2.zip
replace aws/THIRD_PARTY_LICENSES? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to install? AMI, container, virtual machine image? (And why, for what purpose)?

Comment: What happens if you answer `y`? I mean it is asking to update licenses and  your choices are `[y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename`. Usually the answer is `y` with no harm; other options are there just in case they are needed.

Comment: Doing the aws course on Udemy using the terminal on my MacBook Air.  I have input all of the choices and still says same thing when I go to input that zip file

Comment: I hit A for all and this is what I get after entering my password.           /aws/install: line 78: /Users/nicole/aws/dist/aws: cannot execute binary file
Found preexisting AWS CLI installation: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current. Please rerun install script with --update flag.
nicole@Nicoles-Air ~ %